# how break the page between the 2 parts of tcblisting

Tags: tcblisting

As soon as the latex code is too long, the second frame is not displayed correctly.

How to cut the box of tcblisting so that the listing on the one hand and its execution is in two separate frames

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikzducks}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcblisting}{title={Birthday duck}}
very long text latex

very long text latex

very long text latex

very long text latex

very long text latex

very long text latex

very long text latex

very long text latex

very long text latex

very long text latex

very long text latex

very long text latex

very long text latex

very long text latex

very long text latex

very long text latex



\begin{tikzpicture}
    \duck[cake]
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{tcblisting}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add the `breakable` option:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikzducks}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcblisting}{title={Birthday duck},breakable}
very long text latex

very long text latex

very long text latex

very long text latex

very long text latex

very long text latex

very long text latex

very long text latex

very long text latex

very long text latex

very long text latex

very long text latex

very long text latex

very long text latex

very long text latex

very long text latex



\begin{tikzpicture}
    \duck[cake]
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{tcblisting}

\end{document}
```